# Python - Scraping Audio from behind a javascript button

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, audio

I am just starting to learn Python and I decided to jump into the deep end and tackle a fairly difficult problem that I am interested in solving. I would like to scrape the audio files from a website(http://iknow.jp/courses/566921 ) hidden behind buttons.

I cannot find the links to the audio clip in the HTML source code and I think that the code is dynamically ran using Javascript when you click the play buttons. below is the code for the button.

```
<div class="item-audio-container">
    <span title="Play Audio" class="glyph glyph-volume-max">
        ::Before
    </span>  
</div>
```

I thought about intercepting the request or response from when it asks for the audio file but I don't know how to do that and I cannot find any info on it online.

Unfortunately, I cannot see anywhere where I can extract the URL for the audio track. I would like to be able to extract the Audio track with the text beside the button so they can renamed with a meaningful name later on.

Any ideas on how to extract the audio files would be much appreciated.

The code I am using now, which just clicks the Audio button and can be edited to click all buttons in the website.

```
import os, sys
import requests, bs4 , openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import wget

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://iknow.jp/courses/566921')
itemlist = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('item')
#print(itemlist)
word = itemlist[0].find_element_by_class_name('cue')
print(word.text)
audio = itemlist[0].find_element_by_tag_name('span')
audio.click()
```

The imports are just suggestions for useful tools that may help. I am not using them all